# Apache Virtual Hosts

Tags: 16.04, virtualhost, apache2.4

I am looking to create links on my website like support.mydomain.com or management.mydomain.com rather than mydomain.com/support etc. I have heard you can do it with apache virtual hosts but I am not sure how I would set it up.

I am on apache 2.4 and ubuntu 16.04

Comment: You need to register the names `support.mydomain.com`, `management.mydomain.com` as aliases for `mydomain.com` with you friendly DNS service provider, then you need to read the fine documentation at [Apache.org](http://httpd.apache.org/), especially the [Apache Virtual Host Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/). The implementation of Apache HTTP Server on Debian-derived system has some particularities, and you must also read the supplied file `/usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz`.

Comment: @AlexP thanks for the help, what section in particular should I look at in the Apache Virtual Host Documentation

Comment: Be sure that you fully understand how virtual hosts work; don't just skim, read it all, then create a toy configuration on a spare server or a virtual machine. Please note that the official documentation is written for a traditional setup, where all the configuration directives are in one file named `httpd.conf`. On Ubuntu, as on all Debian-derived systems, the configuration of Apache is split into multiple files; read the [HTTPD - Apache2 Web Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html) chapter of the Ubuntu Server Guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **Apache2** distribution comes with a very easy to use **modular configuration**.

Copy your `000-default.conf` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` to a file by then name you will call your virtual site.  Use the configuraton file `000-default.conf` as a template.

In this case you have indicated `mydomain.com`.  You also indicated `management.mydomain.com`.  You can use both to refer to access the same site.  In these steps I'll use `mydomain.com`.

You can use any name for the configuration file.  Using a name that includes the name you'll for your virtual host will make it easier to manage your sites if you make a number of them.

Run these steps.  I numbered them to make it easy for you to point out which step, if any, you get stuck or don't understand.  The `$` is there to represent the terminal prompt where you type your command.  The command is the text you see after the `$` prompt.

```
1. $ mkdir -p /home/web/mysite/www
2. $ mkdir -p /home/web/mysite/log
3. $ cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
4. $ sudo cp 000-default.conf mydomain.conf
5. $ gksudo gedit mydomain.conf
```

**Change from:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

**Change to:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias management.mydomain.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /home/web/www
    <Directory /home/web/ubunzeus/www>
        Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI +Includes
        # AllowOverride All
        # New directive needed in Apache 2.4.3: 
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    
    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog /home/web/mydomain/log/error.log
    CustomLog /home/web/mydomain/log/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Continue the following commands to activate the changes:

```
6. $ sudo a2ensite mydomain.conf
7. $ sudo service apache2 restart
```

With those steps, you can now access your new virtual host by typing the name you have given it into the web browser.

Place your **webcontent** (your **html** files) into the directory you created for your virtual host.  In this example it's: `/home/web/www`.  Your web directory can be placed anywhere on your system.  You just need to configure your virtual host config file with the information.

Anytime you make a change to your Apache2 configuration files be sure to reload it to make the changes become effective.

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: `sudo service apache2 reload` will be enough I think.