# Change phpMyAdmin port from 80 to another number

Tags: 16.04, apache2, phpmyadmin

How to change phpMyAdmin port from `80` to `99`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just to be clear, this is not a setting of PhpMyAdmin, it is a setting of the configuration of Apache2, and we need to create new VirtualHost for this purpose.

**1. Understanding of the default configuration of PhpMyAdmin.** By default (within Ubuntu 16.04) PhpMyAdmin is included (and enabled) into the Apache's configuration (*for all VirtualHosts!*) through this additional configuration file:

```
/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf
```

This file is a [symbolic link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108771/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hard-link-and-a-symbolic-link) to the file `/etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf`, which is a symbolic link to the file `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`, which will be used in the next step.

**2. Create new VirtualHost configuration file.** Let's call it `phpmyadmin.conf` and create it by `nano` (or you can use your favorite text editor):

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/phpmyadmin.conf
```

The content of this file should looks like:

```
Listen 99

<VirtualHost *:99>

        ServerName localhost

        <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
                AllowOverride None
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        DocumentRoot /usr/share/phpmyadmin

        Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/phpmyadmin.error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/phpmyadmin.access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Where:

- [`Listen 99`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#listen) instructs Apache2 to listen on port `99`. Like @L.D.James [says](https://askubuntu.com/a/897003/566421) you can put this directive in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` or you can leave it here;
- [`<VirtualHost *:99>...</VirtualHost>`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost) defines a VirtualHost which will handle the requests form all interfaces (`*`) on port `:99`.
- [`ServerName localhost`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html) this directive is optional and can be customised according to your needs. (Usually there have `ServerName` set on the Server level - in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`);
- [`<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>...</Directory>`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory) this directive is optional because the access permissions for `/usr/share/` are usually set in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. But you can add specific rules here, for example you can [`Set Up Password Authentication`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-password-authentication-with-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04);
- [`DocumentRoot /usr/share/phpmyadmin`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot) this directive sets `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` as directory that forms the main document tree visible from the web, for the current VirtualHost;
- [`Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#include) this directive includes the default phpMyAdmin's configuration into Apache's configuration. Thus `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` will be included only for the current VirtualHost! Instead of this directive you can copy/paste the content of `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` in this place.

**3. Switch Apache's configuration and restart it.**

```
sudo a2disconf phpmyadmin
sudo a2ensite phpmyadmin
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

Where:

- `a2disconf phpmyadmin` will disable the default phpMyAdmin's configuration, described in **1.**
- `a2ensite phpmyadmin` will enable the new VirtualHost, described in **2.**

---

**!!.** Edit `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` and comment (`#`) the first `Alias` directive like thath:

```
#Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

This step is optional, but otherwise `http://localhost:99` and `http://localhost:99/phpmyadmin` will provide identical result, so I suppose we do not need that :)

---

**!!.** If you want this new VirtualHost to be accessible from the outside don't forget to add port `99` into your firewall's rules. If you use [UFW](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall) you can do that by this command:

```
sudo ufw allow 99/tcp
```

With [iptables](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-basic-iptables-firewall-on-centos-6) you can do that by this command:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 99 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 6):

**Adding access via port 99 is quick and easy**

Add the port 99 to your Apache2 configuration.  Edit `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`.  Add the directive `Listen 99`:

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 80
Listen 99

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

This adds **port 99** to the available access.  To disable **port 80** where you can only have access via port 99, comment out or remove the `Listen 80` from the configuration.

**Disabling the default port is a little more detailed**

In most circumstance, disabling the default port 80 isn't necessary.

If you have other sites that you need to have access to port 80 and the `Listen` directive to that Virtualhost.

Alternatively, you could restrict Phpmyadmin to only one specific port by creating a **Phpmyadmin** version host and use the **Listen 99** directive to that virtual host.

Details for creating a virtual host for Apache2 can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/883633/29012):

Make a symbolic link to `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` the virtualhost `document root`.